# Changing position of pre-form help text

Tags: profile

I'm customising the CSS on my profile page - I've learned a lot doing this! I've got it almost how I want it. The last thing I'd like to change is the position of the pre-form help text on some custom fields - they currently float above the text box and label, and I would like them to appear immediately below the field label, to the left of the text box. I've googled and searched StackExchange and not found an answer - any ideas?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Moving html can be done using javascript. You can embed javascript code to move the pre help field just below the label or text field. Here are the references for it 
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/region/